# How can I Navigate to the same page and have it trigger the normal new page lifecycle?

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigation

If you're on `MyPage.xaml` and call Navigate(new Uri("MyPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative)); nothing happens.

How do you get it to actually reload the page?

Comment: I asked this question so it'd exist as a resource on the internet, I can't seem to answer my own question though so the answer is to ensure that you're hitting a unique url. You can do this by simplying tacking something unique on the querystring NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(string.Format("/MyPage.xaml?random={0}", Guid.NewGuid()), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)); for example

Comment: I like your so called "hack" as a solution. You don't have to mess around with getting the state back to zero and raising a bunch of changed properties. You can remove the current page entry from the backstack when navigating away too so your backstack doesn't have the same page twice. The hack is ideal in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already said a quick and dirty way to cause a page refresh. But it seems to me you may not need to do it. Refreshes of the data using the Silverlight data binding and raising property changes and an MVVM model for your page seems a much better fit. But not knowing the use case makes it harder to say

The other thing is, wouldn't navigating to a new page, that is the same page mess up the stack? You could end up having a situation where a user needs to back navigate a large number of pages.

Comment: Agreed, it's definitely a dirty hack and yes you'd have to pop the backstack. A 'better' way to do it is certainly to refresh the models for the page. In my particular case it's a SL-XNA gamepage where there is a lot of initialisation code, by far the easiest way to restart the game here is to navigate back to the page.